# Show that differential map $df : TM \to \mathbb{R}$ of a smooth map $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tangent-bundle

I'm trying to prove that for any smooth map $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$ on a manifold $M$ to the real numbers, the map $df : TM \to \mathbb{R}$ from the tangent bundle $TM$ to the real numbers given by $df(v) = v(f)$ is smooth.

I was told that I need to show that every component of $df$ is smooth, using a coordinate map of the tangent bundle $TM$ (with respect to a chart on $M$ and the natural projection map from $TM$ to $M$).

I'm pretty sure that I need to show that $df$ is smooth with respect to any given smooth vector field on $M$. My plan was to show that the composition of the inverse of a chart of $TM$ and $df$ is a smooth diffeomorphism, as one proves that any vector field can be written as a linear combination of smooth functions and the partial derivitive of the components of a chart. But I'm having a hard time trying to write out each components explicitly. I would love some helps!!

P.S. I'm new here, and I apologive that I don't know how to write mathematical symbols as in LaTeX when asking a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices to check that ${\rm d}f\colon TM \to \Bbb R$ is smooth in enough charts to cover $TM$. If $(U, \varphi)$ is a chart in $M$, we have a induced chart in $TM$ given by $(TU,\widetilde{\varphi})$, given as follows: if $\varphi = (x^1,\ldots, x^n)$, we write a tangent vector as $$v_p = \sum_{i=1}^n a^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\bigg|_p,$$ and put $\widetilde{\varphi}(v_p) = (x^1(p),\ldots, x^n(p), a^1,\ldots, a^n)$. We of course have that the inverse is $$\widetilde{\varphi}^{-1}(p^1,\ldots, p^n, v^1,\ldots, v^n) = \sum_{i=1}^n v^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\bigg|_{\varphi^{-1}(p^1,\ldots, p^n )}.$$Then $$\begin{align} {\rm d}f \circ \widetilde{\varphi}^{-1}(p^1,\ldots, p^n, v^1,\ldots, v^n) &= {\rm d}f\left(\sum_{i=1}^n v^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\bigg|_{\varphi^{-1}(p^1,\ldots, p^n )} \right)\\ &=\sum_{i=1}^n v^i \,{\rm d}f\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\bigg|_{\varphi^{-1}(p^1,\ldots, p^n)}\right) \\ &= \sum_{i=1}^n v^i \frac{\partial(f\circ \varphi^{-1})}{\partial x^i}(p^1,\ldots, p^n)\end{align}$$is smooth in the variables $(p^1,\ldots,p^n, v^1,\ldots, v^n)$, since $f$ being smooth tells us that $$(p^1,\ldots, p^n) \mapsto \frac{\partial(f\circ \varphi^{-1})}{\partial x^i}(p^1,\ldots, p^n) $$is smooth.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanx:)

Comment: You're welcome (to math.stackexchange too)! If you need any clarifying you can tell me. Or click in the green checkmark to accept the answer (so the question does not stay in the unanswered list) :-)

Comment: +1 For clear answer.